# How to lock the node.js function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using embedded array in mongoDB, Document looks same as below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("516f89b393307a0f73533863"),
    "desc" : "LrOBVgWHHRyAxgYdKIwwgATcGTNBlz",
    "comments" :[
                 { 
                     "comment" : "superb",
                     "likeOrUnlike" : [
                          {"name":"kk",
                           "date":"2013/04/11",
                            "like":true
                           }
                      ]
                 }
      ]
   "date" : ISODate("2013-04-18T05:50:43.112Z"),
   "title" : "OaTHxDDMoINSaZCHCSNpJLNQyrqXGZ"

}
```

I want to `update` the date and like field in the likeOrUnlike array inside the comments, Automic update is not possible in this scenario,  so i thought of doing it manually by code(retrieving whole document and update),

In this case concurrency issue will occur

`scenario :` If two persons likes the same comment at same time.

So the solution is to lock the particular update function

```
 var updateComments = function(id,data){
     db.posts.findOne({"_id" :id},function(err,res){
        // stuff   
        //mongo update
     });
 };
```

I can't post entire code.

My Question is

How to lock the function in node.js?

locking node.js function is good practice?

Comment: I don't think mongodb allow multiple writes at same time. When you are going to insert or update data for any document in collection mongodb lock the whole collection.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/

use mongodb positional operator to update object inside a array

Answer (score 0):

Locking should be a last resort.  Use $push ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/ ) or another collection.